# strtrok_s function does not take 2 arguments

Tags: c++, visual-c++

// A simple program that interprets spaces and commas as delimeters (seperate characters)

// and prints each substring-that is, each token-on its own line:

```
#include "stdafx"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){

char the_string[81], *p;

cout << "Input a string to parse: ";
cin.getline(the_string, 81);
p = strtok_s(the_string, ", ");
while (p != nullptr) {
cout << p << endl;
p = strtok_s(nullptr, ", ");

}


return 0;
```

}

This are the problems it gives me Error 1 error C2660: 'strtok_s' : function does not take 2 arguments

IntelliSense: too few arguments in function call

Comment: Please read [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3.aspx) for the `strtok_s` function, and fix your code according to the documentation. You're not passing all required arguments to the function.

Comment: Do you know how to look up the docs?  I use Google search term 'site:msdn.microsoft.com strtok_s' and get to [`strtok_s()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3.aspx) for VS 2015.  The observation in your question title is correct: `strtok_s()` does not take two arguments (even though plain `strtok()` does — but there are solid reasons for not using `strtok()`).

Comment: I use strtok() but it dosent let me run the program it says its safer to use strtok_s()

Comment: I am following a book and all it gives me is strtok() for the example and the compiler says to me to use strtok_s()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is only *recommending* the Safer CRT functions, and it also gives you instructions for turning off the warnings if you really want to use the original `strtok` function:

```
warning C4996: 'strtok': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider
using strtok_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNING
```

Just add `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNING` as a Preprocessor Define in your project settings or add to the top of your stdafx.h file `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNING 1`

See [Security Features in the CRT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ef0s5kh.aspx)

You are clearly very new to C/C++, so you don't need to worry about this detail just yet. The reason this warning is here is because many of the long-standard C string library functions that date back to [Kernighan & Ritchie's original language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) have some inherent security problems in the modern world of malware. As such, any production application should avoid them favor of the "Safer CRT" versions.

In particular `strtok` works by having internal hidden state in the library, which can sometimes be exploited to create security problems in parsers.

```
char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);
```

The `strtok_s` function simply takes an explicit context variable to use for the state instead of the hidden internal variable. It works exactly the same as `strtok` in all other ways.

```
char *strtok_s(char *strToken, const char *strDelimit, char **context);
```

Therefore, your code would do exactly the same thing as your book sample as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){

char the_string[81], *p;
char *next_token = nullptr;

cout << "Input a string to parse: ";
cin.getline(the_string, 81);
p = strtok_s(the_string, ", ", &next_token);
while (p != nullptr) {
cout << p << endl;
p = strtok_s(nullptr, ", ", &next_token);
}


return 0;
}
```

For more information and history on the Safer CRT, see [Security Development Lifecycle (SDL) Banned Function Calls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288454.aspx)